# xlwings: How to acquire the value of the cell and to indicate message box

Tags: python, winapi, messagebox, xlwings

I'm using xlwings on a Windows.
I acquire the value of the cell and want to indicate message box.

```
import xlwings as xw
import win32ui

def msg_box():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    win32ui.MessageBox(xw.sheets[0].range(4, 1).value,"MesseageBox")
```

However, Python stops. Could anyone help me to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, something like this should work as a workaround:

```
import xlwings as xw
import win32api

def msg_box():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    win32api.MessageBox(wb.app.hwnd, "YourMessage")
```

Comment: Thank you for Felix.However my message is value of the cell.

Comment: Just replace `"YourMessage"` with `xw.sheets[0].range((4, 1)).value` - mind the tuple in `range`.

Comment: I replaced it,an error happend.TypeError: Objects of type 'float' can not be converted to Unicode.

Comment: turn it into string: `str(xw.sheets[0].range((4, 1)).value)`

Comment: It code worked, and I was able to understand problem.Thank you Felix.